# Row-slider for the rendered table made using R - DataTable for ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have to display a large data frame on shiny-mainPanel(). I am using `library("DT")` for the purpose with `renderDT({})` and `datatable(df,rownames = FALSE)`. The rows in the data frame have very long string values which are distorting the shape of the rendered table on the mainPanel.

Here is the **distorted-table** with all the columns
[image: Distorted Table]

Here is the **clean-table** with fewer columns
[image: Organized Table]

I want the display all the columns just like displayed in the **clean-table**. I am trying to make a slider for gliding through the rows but couldn't find any in-built option for `datatable()`

function on the **UI**

```
mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
```

function on the **Server**

```
 output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df,rownames = FALSE)})
```

Comment: could you provide a example of a row with very long string value using `dput()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option `scrollX = TRUE` in Datatable.
All the options of the Datatable javascript library, in particular [`scrollX`](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html), can be [set in Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html) using the `òptions` parameter.
Try :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'DataTable Options',
  tabPanel('Display length',     DT::dataTableOutput('ex1'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # A lot of columns
  df <- cbind(head(mtcars),head(iris)) 
  output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(df, options = list(scrollX = T))
  )
}

shinyApp(server = server,ui)
```